# iOS 5 network data being persistant even after refresh/restart of app

Tags: network-programming, ios5

I have an app that grabs (async) a JSON file on the network during startup.  The app starts fresh when restarted.  It has some config settings, as the app acts as a shell.  My issue is when I change the config file on the server, the old settings remain the same. As if it's being cached. This has happened in several apps I have, and it started when I updated to iOS5.

I have an Android app that's equivalent, but does not suffer from this issue.

Comment: Have you tried playing with `NSURLRequestCachePolicy` on the `NSURLRequest` that you're using to get the JSON file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSURLRequestCachePolicy is correct.